# What <COMMAND> will make `declare -A ASSOCIATIVEARRAY=( $( <COMMAND> ) )` work?

Tags: bash, shell-script, associative-array

`bash` evaluates the following expression without any objections:

```
declare -A SPANISH=( [rojo]=red [verde]=green [azul]=blue )
```

...but it does not like this one one bit:

```
declare -A SPANISH=( $( echo "[rojo]=red [verde]=green [azul]=blue" ) )
bash: SPANISH: $( echo "[rojo]=red [verde]=green [azul]=blue" ): must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

I have tried many variations, but the result is always one or more instances of the `must use subscript when assigning associative array` error shown above.

This example is silly, of course.  Its only purpose is to illustrate the problem of *initializing a **bash** associative array using a command substitution*.

Can this be done?

To be concrete, and to continue with the silly example above, what would be a command `<COMMAND>` such that

```
declare -A SPANISH=( $( <COMMAND> ) )
```

...produces the same final result as that produced by

```
declare -A SPANISH=( [rojo]=red [verde]=green [azul]=blue )
```

above?

Incidentally, `zsh` handles this situation without any problem:

```
$ declare -A SPANISH=( $( echo "rojo red verde green azul blue" ) )
$ echo "${SPANISH[azul]}"
blue
```

Comment: Related: [Making associative array based on another associative array](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/464626)

Comment: What version of bash are you using? On my machine, with bash 5.1.16(1)-release, I get no errors, and the array is created just not correctly: I get a single element, the string `[rojo]=red [verde]=green [azul]=blue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare -A "SPANISH=($(echo '[rojo]=red [verde]=green [azul]=blue'))"
```

Or:

```
declare -A "SPANISH=$(echo '([rojo]=red [verde]=green [azul]=blue)')"
```

Or:

```
declare -A "$(echo 'SPANISH=([rojo]=red [verde]=green [azul]=blue)')"
```

For that matters,

Work for me with bash 5.1, though you might as well use `eval` as that's essentially what's happening here, bash ends up interpreting the output of the command as code.

For instance, with

```
cmd() { echo '[x$(reboot)]=y'; }
```

```
declare -A "a=($(cmd))"
```

Would run `reboot` just the same as:

```
eval "
  declare -A a=($(cmd))
"
```

Using `eval` explicitly would make it clearer that there's a path for a command injection vulnerability, and is more likely to be future-proof in case that messed up design is fixed in the future.

For a safer approach, you can get your `cmd` to output keys and values NUL-delimited (as bash variables can't contain NULs anyway) and fill up your associative array in a loop, with the additional usual caveat that associative arrays in bash can't have elements with an empty key.

```
fill_assoc() {
  local -n _assoc="$1"
  local _key _value
  while
    IFS= read -rd '' _key &&
    IFS= read -rd '' _value
  do
     _assoc[$_key]=$_value
  done
}
```

```
typeset -A assoc
fill_assoc assoc < <(printf '%s\0' rojo red verde green azul blue)
```

Comment: @terdon, take note of where the quotes are in there. The key being to quote the `(` and `)`.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed. I (stupidly) assumed you were just using the OP's command. Thanks!